# Adding more than one behavior to a FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

duiring my last project I discovered the Android Material Design Library. It is pretty mighty and I had fun working with it. I added a custom behavior to my FloatingActionButton, so it disappears while scrolling downwards. Now I mentioned, if a SnackBar is shown the position of the FAB isn't handled automatically anymore.

After some debugging I found out, that setting the anchor to the recyclerView and adding the customBehaviour for scrolling the default behavior from the CoordinatorLayout depending the SnackBar is gone.

So I ask myself, can I add more then one Behaviour to my FAB? Or can I somehow tell it, that the defualt one should not be overwritten, but extended?

Or can I write more than one of those?

```
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fab, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof RecyclerView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a method to realise the wished behavior, but it has more of an workaround than an answer.

If I add the Scrollbehavior programmatically in the Java Code like this:

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState ==  RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                sendMailFAB.show();
            }
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0 && sendMailFAB.isShown())
                sendMailFAB.hide();
        }
    });
```

And then delete the custom behavior and it's anchor in the .xml file, the CoordinatorLayout's default behavior handles the Snackbar and the onScrollListener the scroll behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.flowment.designExample.StartActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/startRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <!-- DELETE THIS PART, BECAUSE IT'S NOT USED ANYMORE AND BLOCKS THE DEFAULT.
    app:layout_anchor="@id/startRecyclerView"
    app:layout_behavior="de.flowment.designExample.FABScrollBehavior" />-->


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So I achived two behavior, but like I said this is more of an workaround.

Comment: The question still remains in 2019. Did you find any solid answer?